# Acessing a element in Treeset using index

Tags: java, treeset

Suppose there is a string treeset (ts)of elemnent 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
Is there is any in built method in treeset so that i can access an element.
For eg accessing 3 can i do ts.[2]and accessing  8 ts.[7].(something like that).
i used this method:

```
     Iterator<String> it = ts.iterator();
      int i=0;
       while(it.hasNext()) {
           String ele=it.next();
           if(i==2){
               System.out.println(ele+"");
           }
           i++;
      }
```

though when i ran it didn't showed any o/p but if i did **i=0** then it showed all the o/p i.e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Secondly can anyone tell me that when it is best to use hashset,treeset and linkedhashset

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna access elements in your collection like ts[2], then you should better convert your collection into array using collection inbuilt method.

Otherwise, using iterator is the standard and efficient way to access elements in collection.

For second question, Hashset is used as hash table ; LinkedHashSet is used as hash table with elements stored in same way as inserted; TreeSet is used for collection using navigations.

For complete knowledge you must check Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` is a `NavigableSet`which means you have an order of items (natural ordering as default, but you can define your own ordering relationship by using `Comparator` or `Comparable` interface) and you can navigate through items by this order. However there is no index mechanism. Basically a `TreeSet` is based on a `TreeMap` which is a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). In such a data structure indexes (element indexes, not indexes in the sense of efficient access) are not much meaningfull.

`HashSet` on the other hand is based on a `HashMap` which is a classical [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implementation. In this data structure there is no order defined. You can look up each item at `O(1)` time though due to hash function used.

`LinkedHashSet` is a subclass of `HashSet`. Other then `HashSet` methods no new method is defined, so `LinkedHashSet` does not allow any more capability like natural order or indexes. However it has an auxilary linked list that keeps track of the order in which elements are inserted. In this way when you iterate over a `LinkedHashSet` by `.iterator()` method or a for loop you get elements in the order you inserted.

So basically a `HashSet` is more appropriate if you will access elements individually. Or being the simplest `Set` implementation you can use `HashSet` in generic cases. If you need to keep the order of insertion you need to use `LinkedHashSet` and if you have to enforce any custom ordering or natural ordering of items you should use `TreeSet`.